# Is there an existing writer/parser for the logback.xml that can be used to edit existing files?

Tags: java, logback

I'm wondering if this already exists, or if I need to implement it myself.
I'd basically like to be able to update the contents of an existing `logback.xml` programatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a project in github](https://github.com/enricopulatzo/logback-XSD) which aims to provide an XML Schema definition for the logback configuration file. You can work from there to create a parser/writer with [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) or [Castor](http://castor.exolab.org/) or your prefered XML Library.

Comment: Why isn't this just contributed back to the logback project...? So... what -- I need something like the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate the classes for me based on the XSD? Is there really no other way? I was expecting `logback` to be a bit more mature of a project, based on the fact that I've already seen this sort of functionality in a number of products? Did they all just have to knock up their own implementations?

Comment: Well, according to [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731162/xml-schema-or-dtd-for-logback-xml) and its links, Logback dev team considered the XML configuration file too flexible to specify an XML Schema or DTD for it.