# Eclipse shows nasty white cross in red circle with no message

Tags: xml, eclipse

This is me just trying to get rid of warning messages.

My logback xml files start rather baldly with "<configuration>..." which gives a warning about no "XML or DTD constraints".

So an [answer here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731162/xml-schema-or-dtd-for-logback-xml) suggests putting these two lines at the top of the file:

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
```

When I do that, however, I get a nasty white cross in a red circle with no error message from Eclipse.

[image: nasty white cross in red circle]

Can anyone identify the problem and hopefully the solution?

Comment: Thanks.  This the whole point: there is NOTHING there, not an error, not a warning.

Comment: No text is shown when you hover over those icons, or in the **Problems** View?

Also: `<?xml?>` is case sensitive. It must be lower case.

Comment: @nitind Tx. Case-sensitive - never knew that, and I presume you mean even in a Windows OS.  Absolutely no text of any kind showing.  NB Eclipse is version 4.10.0.  Having said the above, I just launched again and there are no errors currently showing.

Comment: It's the file format, the O.S. doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link - might be helpful I think -  take a look at the first two/three answers:

[No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551783/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document)

First try changing `<!DOCTYPE configuration>` to `<!DOCTYPE xml>`

Comment: Thanks. Thought I'd found a workaround: File --> New --> Other --> XML --> XML file. This gives an xml file with the initial <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> line... and no nasty white-cross-and-red-circle. It is then just a matter of copying the content of the "defective file" to the new one. NB encoding of "defective" file is UTF-8, exactly the same as the new file.. later: unfortunately, next time I launch Eclipse the same "no grammar constraints" warning comes back (though the white cross in red circle has gone).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I had found an answer.

Having inserted these two lines at the top of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
```

... I then found I have to position the cursor e.g. after "xml" and backspace... and then re-type the characters `<?xml` ... After this the nasty symbol went away.

I'm no great expert on encoding but this may be something to do with those funny "initial bytes" of a file which indicate what encoding it's using (Big-Endian, Little-Endian).

However, I then find that next time I launch Eclipse the same "no grammar constraints" warning comes back (though the white cross in red circle has gone).